# Reactjs How to stop the loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, react-native, break

I've been wondering how to stop your loop, like `break` in some programming languages but in React js seems don't working.

something like this:

```
loop(){
  if(){
    //meet the if statement end the loop.
    break;  //not working.
  }
}
```

no actually the loop is a fetch from the server using aPI.

Comment: You question has nothing to do with React :)

Comment: where is the loop (`for`, `while`, `forEach`, `map`, etc)?

Comment: More detail about how this loop function is called is required for you to get a good answer.

Comment: sorry the loop is a fetch statement from the server using API.

Answer (score 10):

Your `loop()` is actually a function which you can `return` from in order to escape it.

```
loop(){
  if(){
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: return is not a solution if there are more other loop after this.

Comment: @Ved without more detail from the OP, this is the only possible solution.

Comment: I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a exit statement for `if` . And `break` do not work with `if` condition.

```
   loop(){
     let breakCondition = false;
      if(actualCondition && !breakCondition ){
        //here actualCondition  is the expression you are using in if.
         breakCondition  = true

      }
    }
```

> And If there is no other code below the `if` condition than check
>   @Soviut answer.

Comment: I think `break` in JavaScript is only used inside a switch case?

Comment: `break` condition can be used inside `for` loop.

Comment: `break` can be used inside *any* loop including `for` and `while`